# is there a way to copy part of pose into another pose

Tags: rigging

I have a not-perfect walkcykle, but in the proces I made a mistake on one bone. I do have a copy of each step I made, therefore I have a walkcykle, which have this bone seved corectly and the other bones are not. is there a way how to combine these two poses?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but the answer will help other people with the same question.

**Yes, you can copy part of a pose into another pose.** The armatures must be identical. The best way is to create a pose library and save both poses.

1. Select the pose from which you'll copy a part and go into pose mode.
   Select the bones to be copied.
   *Tip:* Hold Ctrl when selecting a parent bone and you'll select all the children.
2. Ctrl+C or Pose > Copy pose.
3. Now switch to the pose to be modified. Still in pose mode, Ctrl+V go
   to Pose > Paste Pose.

[image]